# How to perform a conditional where not exists in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is to fetch all unenrolled users – all `users` that don't have enrollments and in the current term sessions. Each term has many courses, which have sessions (therefore all the joins).

In order to do that I tried not in (with no success) and `NOT EXISTS` which works correctly. I know the correctness because there is a spec to validate the results and I'm only replacing a FE 'calculation' with the SQL BE query – which is obviously 100x faster.

I have the following raw SQL query that is bringing me correct results:

```sql
  SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT enrollments.user_id FROM enrollments 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sessions ON sessions.id = enrollments.session_id 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN courses ON courses.id = sessions.course_id 
      WHERE enrollments.user_id = users.id 
      AND sessions.term_id = 7
  )
  AND users.id IN (…);
```

And I'm trying to convert this with Rails, but it did not work out well. I first tried with `NOT IN`, but I see that they are probably no equivalent:

```ruby
User.left_joins(enrollments: :session) # same result with includes
    .where(id: current_students)
    .references(:enrollments)
    .where.not(enrollments: { ces_session: open_enroll_term.session })
    .uniq
```

So I went on to try to implement it with `.exists.not`:

```ruby
User.left_joins(enrollments: :session) # same result with includes
    .where(id: current_students)
    .references(:enrollments)
    .where(enrollments: { session: open_enroll_term.session }).exists.not
```

Which returns actually and Arel object. So not only my query might not be right, but now also I need some Arel on it make it return an ActiveRecord object.

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: I think it would help if you stated in plain English what it is you're trying to get with your query.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion. Hope it is easier to grasp now.

Comment: If you do not send any parameters to `.not`,it will not trigger a query. It's intended use is `.where.not(id: User.enrolled)`. Unfortunately, ActiveRecord does not have a "NOT EXISTS" query method, which means you'll have to rely on a raw SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show your models, I'm going to make some assumptions. In the following models, I'm going to include only the required attributes. Certainly, you will have more (e.g., `Course` would likely have a `name`, `CourseSession` would have a `time`, etc.).

At the end of all this, you will be able to get all the students enrolled in a given term by doing:

```
User.enrolled_for_term(term)
```

And you will be able to get all the students not enrolled in a give term by doing:

```
User.not_enrolled_for_term(term)
```

First, let's assume:

- You have a `Term` model (like "Fall 2019", or "Winter 2019")
- You have a `Course` model (like "Bio 100", or "Chem 100")
- A `Term` can have many `Course`s ("Bio 100" and "Chem 100" might be offered in "Fall 2019")
- A `Course` can be offered in many `Term`s ("Bio 100" might be offered in "Fall 2019" and "Winter 2019")
- You have a `CourseTerm` model that allows for the many-to-many relationship between `Term`s and `Course`s

`Term` might look like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: terms
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
class Term < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :course_terms
  has_many :courses, through: :course_terms
end
```

`Course` might look like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: courses
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :course_terms
  has_many :terms, through: :course_terms
end
```

And `CourseTerm` might look like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: course_terms
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  course_id  :bigint
#  term_id    :bigint
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
class CourseTerm < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :term

  class << self

    def for_term(term)
      where(term: term)
    end

  end

end
```

Notice that you can get all the `CourseTerm`s for a `Term` by using `CourseTerm.for_term(term)`.

Now, let's assume a `Course` can be offed multiple times during a `Term` (e.g., the course might be offered at 9:00AM and 10:00AM). I think this is what you mean by 'sessions'. Let's call this `CourseSession`, which might look like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: course_sessions
#
#  id             :bigint           not null, primary key
#  course_term_id :bigint
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#
class CourseSession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_term

  class << self

    def for_term(term)
      where(course_term: CourseTerm.for_term(term))
    end

  end

end
```

Notice that you can get all the `CourseSession`s for a `Term` by using `CourseSession.for_term(term)`.

Now, let's assume that a `User` can be associated with a `CourseSession` which is what I assume you mean by 'enrollment'. I called this `StudentCourseSession`:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: student_course_sessions
#
#  id                :bigint           not null, primary key
#  student_id        :integer
#  course_session_id :bigint
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#
class StudentCourseSession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_session
  belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"

  class << self

    def for_course_sessions(course_sessions)
      where(course_session: course_sessions)
    end

    def for_term(term)
      for_course_sessions(CourseSession.for_term(term))
    end

  end

end
```

Notice that you can get all the enrollments for a 'Term' by doing `StudentCourseSession.for_term(term)`.

Now, in your 'User' model, you add a `has_many :student_course_sessions` association, specifying `foreign_key: :student_id`. You add an `enrolled_for_term(term)` method that finds all the students enrolled in the specified term. Then, then `not_enrolled_for_term(term)` simply becomes finding the students that are `.not` enrolled for the specified term.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :student_course_sessions, foreign_key: :student_id

  class << self 

    def not_enrolled_for_term(term)
      where.not(id: enrolled_for_term(term)).distinct
    end

    def enrolled_for_term(term)
      joins(:student_course_sessions).
        where(student_course_sessions: {id: StudentCourseSession.for_term(term)}).
        distinct
    end

  end

end
```

Here's an rspec test for the above:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Unenrolled Students" do
  before(:each) do 
    create(:student_course_session, student: user_1, course_session: course_session_1)
    create(:student_course_session, student: user_2, course_session: course_session_2)
    create(:student_course_session, student: user_2, course_session: course_session_3)
  end
  it "works" do 
    expect(User.enrolled_for_term(term_1)).to include(user_1)
    expect(User.enrolled_for_term(term_1)).to include(user_2)
    expect(User.enrolled_for_term(term_1)).not_to include(user_3)

    expect(User.not_enrolled_for_term(term_1)).not_to include(user_1)
    expect(User.not_enrolled_for_term(term_1)).not_to include(user_2)
    expect(User.not_enrolled_for_term(term_1)).to include(user_3)
  end
end

def user_1
  @user_1 ||= create(:user)
end

def user_2
  @user_2 ||= create(:user)
end

def user_3
  @user_3 ||= create(:user)
end

def term_1
  @term_1 ||= create(:term)
end

def course_1
  @course_1 ||= create(:course)
end

def course_2
  @course_2 ||= create(:course)
end

def course_term_1
  @course_term_1 ||= create(:course_term, course: course_1, term: term_1)
end

def course_term_2
  @course_term_2 ||= create(:course_term, course: course_1, term: term_1)
end

def course_term_3
  @course_term_3 ||= create(:course_term, course: course_2, term: term_1)
end

def course_session_1
  @course_session_1 ||= create(:course_session, course_term: course_term_1)
end

def course_session_2
  @course_session_2 ||= create(:course_session, course_term: course_term_2)
end

def course_session_3
  @course_session_3 ||= create(:course_session, course_term: course_term_3)
end

def student_course_session_1
  @student_course_session_1 ||= create(:student_course_session, student: user_1, course_session: course_session_1)
end
```

Which gives:

```
10:55:58 - INFO - Running: spec/so/unenrolled_students_spec.rb

Unenrolled Students
  works

Finished in 0.27546 seconds (files took 1.04 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually have enrollments. So student enrolls to a session. And a session belongs to a course. And a session of course can be given in a term.

The problem is that I have a list of students. From those students, I have to check which ones are not enrolled in this term. The enrolled query is easy. Maybe I can try to follow you tip and negate the enrolled query (though I will have to modify mine because I consider also status of enrollment such as pending, completed, withdrawn.

I guess also the take here is that if it can be done with `where.not` vs NOT exists (SQL).

Comment: If you use the code above, and have a variable called `@students`, then just do `@students.not_enrolled_for_term(term)`. Or perhaps I'm missing an important subtlety.

Comment: thanks for the reply So basically the negation of the enrolled for term. I think it might work, just worried about this being a N+1, while my SQL version is just one query.

Comment: It's all a single query. You know how to use `explain`, right?

Comment: Yes, I know. Let me test this and will get back here if it works. thanks!